# Get all matches from string that start with and end, using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How would I use PHP to extract everything in between `[startstring]` and `[endstring]` from this string:

```
[startstring]hello = guys[endstring] hello guys [startstring]jerk = you[endstring] welcome to the universe
```

I'd like to find all the matches of `[startstring]` and `[endstring]`, and echo the text inside. Kinda like a delimiter. And I would like all the matches echoed to be seperated by a space.

How would I go about accomplishing this? Would this require `regex`? Could you provide a sample?

Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[startstring\](.*?)\[endstring\]/s', $input, $matches);
echo implode(' ', $matches);
```

---

```
preg_match_all('/\[startstring\](.*?)\=(.*?)\[endstring\]/s', $input, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    $key = $matches[1][$i];
    $value = $matches[2][$i];
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: In `$hello` and `$jerk`, just like you said. Just run it, echo the variables and try it out!

Answer (score 4):

Try with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
preg_match_all('/\[startstring\](.*?)\[endstring\]/', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: `(.*?)` means a lot of backtracking, but it's by far the simplest method and will be fine. Hope the string isn't huge ;-)

Comment: @DoubleGras It is going to be huge... :( What do you recommend?

Comment: How would I go about making each match into a variable? Like making `hello = guys` a real, useable variable in my script? `$hello = guys`

Comment: I don't think it's as *huge* as I meant ;) Don't worry, optimizing this code is probably the *least* of your concerns, really. About dynamically creating variables as you suggested, forget it: unsecure, crash-prone, etc.

Comment: @DoubleGras no, I mean huge. Like I'm doing a whole document. Would it still be speedy? or what? thanks for your help

Comment: You'll just have a bit of backtracking between [startstring] and [endstring], so it's completely acceptable (I'd say almost perfect). Only problem is if your document is malformed (a missing [endstring]). By huge I meant tens of MB's between [startstring] and [endstring].