# Extract string that begins with and ends with

Tags: php, regex

I would like to extract the following string `<%MYSTRING123%>` from the example string below

```
'sdfsdf sdfsdf fd<%MYSTRING123%>d12df fsdsgsg d'
```

I found this exact [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308154/get-all-matches-from-string-that-start-with-and-end-using-php) has been asked already, so i tried their solution as below:

```
$input = 'sdfsdf sdfsdf fd<%MYSTRING123%>d12df fsdsgsg d';
preg_match_all('/\[<%MYSTRING\](.*?)\[%>\]/', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> '<%MYSTRING123%>'
}
```

[Link to PHP example](http://ideone.com/cdjNax)

Comment: Try this https://eval.in/799730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `preg_match_all()` you will always get a 2-dimensional array. This will at least give you the content you are looking for:

`/<%MYSTRING\d+%>/`

https://regex101.com/r/abVAkC/1

http://ideone.com/I8VRoV

PS: the `\[` and `\]` in the topic you linked are part of their input ('BBCode'-tags). So these do not apply for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your regex, it seems you need to be able to get `<%MYSTRING-anynumber%>`, right?

Try to change a bit your regex the following:

```
<?php
$input = 'sdfsdf sdfsdf fd<%MYSTRING123%>d12df fsdsgsg d';
preg_match_all('/\<%MYSTRING.*?%>/', $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/JNSnXm)